# Is it possible to convert a (Leaflet) route into a polyline?

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I'm currently making a map with roads that I have driven in the past. Right now, for one route I enter a few waypoints, and the route is calculated through these waypoints using OSRM.

It works fine, but the problem is that on every pageload this route will be recalculated (which makes sense, cause that's how routing works). Let's say I have 50 routes, that'll be a lot of requests. However, I want to be able to calculate the route once, and save the line that is generated as a polyline, which essentially caches the route forever.

Since the routes all stay the same, and no recalculation is necessary, this would be the best way, because then I don't need to setup my own OSRM server or pay for a routing service. (I might need to recalculate routes every once in a while, but that's alright).

Is this way of converting/cachine routes possible? It would be great if I could get this project working live without any routing attached to it.

Thanks for your help in advance!